# How to change "Buy it now" button text for Shopify product on Ride theme?

Tags: json, shopify, e-commerce, liquid

I am trying to create a product template in the Ride theme on Shopify so I can change the "Buy it now" text on the buy button of the product. I have done it before when dealing with a .liquid based theme, but on the Ride theme the product template is JSON. I have no idea what to do with this JSON code. Here is the JSON code that displays the buy button and add to cart button in the Ride theme.

```
"buy_buttons": {
      "type": "buy_buttons",
      "settings": {
        "show_dynamic_checkout": true
      }
    },
```

What do I do here, in the theme.liquid file, or anywhere else so that I can change the text on the buy button?

Comment: If the answer below helped, please consider marking it as an Accepted Answer :D

Comment: If I had multiple products (one being pre-order only and one not), I would need a different solution, but for my one product site this is perfect! Thanks! @ItsGageH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to update the text without having to edit the code by looking for the 'translation' in the Languages section of the theme. The section can be accessed from the Themes page, as per the image below:

[image: Shopify theme customisation dropdown]

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to change the text of Buy It Now button is using a Shopify app also. That way your existing code and Shopify store settings remains the same and you will be able to change the text of Buy It Now button.
Advanced Product Customizer Shopify app have this free feature to change the text of Buy It Now button.

Here is the link for more details -
https://newapputil.blogspot.com/2024/02/how-to-change-text-and-color-of-buy-it.html